# How to remove 2003 server roles without cd-rom?

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, windows

Trying to remove a few server roles on a 2003 server but its asking me to put the cd-rom disk in. Wondering if there's another way to remove roles without putting the cd-rom as it's a VM and I don't have physical access to the host, not sure why I would need the disk for removing roles anyways. Thanks

Comment: Mount an ISO image of the CD-ROM?

Answer (score 3):

It needs the i386 directory from the CD-ROM.  If you thought ahead and saved that to the VM's disk somewhere, you can put the path to that directory in.  If not, you need to make a copy of the directory, or mount an [ISO] image of the CD.

[image: Mount ISO]

Answer (score 0):

If the VM is running off a VM ESXi host, you can also upload a copy of the Win2K3 ISO to the datastore.  That way, it's always available in the future.  You can also mount ISO's directly from the datastore.  Point is, unless you copied the i386 folder to the VM, you need a copy of the installation media somewhere.